# Red neuronal con R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando hacer una red neuronal en R. Estos son mis datos, y deseo saber si a oartir de determinadas caracteristicas el resultado del tratamiento para los pacientes es positivo o negativo:
[image: Al conjunto de datos le he llamdo: uno]

```
library(MASS)
ibrary(neuralnet)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(65)
datos    <- uno
datos<-as.data.frame(datos)
n        <- nrow(datos)
muestra  <- sample(n, n * .70)
train    <- datos[muestra, ]
test     <- datos[-muestra, ]
maxs      <- apply(train, 2, max)
mins      <- apply(train, 2, min)
datos_nrm <- as.data.frame(scale(datos, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
train_nrm <- datos_nrm[muestra, ]
test_nrm  <- datos_nrm[-muestra, ]
maxs      <- apply(train, 2, max)
mins      <- apply(train, 2, min)
datos_nrm <- as.data.frame(scale(datos, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
train_nrm <- datos_nrm[muestra, ]
test_nrm  <- datos_nrm[-muestra, ]

nms  <- names(train_nrm)
frml <- as.formula(paste("Result_of_Treatment~", 
paste(nms[!nms %in% "Result_of_Treatment"], collapse = " + ")))
```

El aviso que me da es el siguiente y por eso la red no da los resultados esperados:
*AVISO: Warning in if (nchar(cmd) <= width) return(cmd) :
la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado*

Los datos originales con los que se hacen el script, son unos datos de base de R que se llaman Boston, cuando lo ejecuto con ese conjunto de datos no sale esta advertencia.

```
datos    <- Boston
```

Alguien sabe a que se debe este error?????

Comment: Como sugerencia: El fragmento con la muestra de los datos que usas, también se podía poner como texto.

Comment: Acabo de correr tu código usando `Boston` y no tengo ningún error. Por las dudas reinicia la sesión de R y vuelve a cargar los paquetes.

Comment: Con Boston no da ningun error, pero con mi conjunto de datos si da error. No entiendo porque si mis datos son semejantes al conjunto de datos Boston.             nms  <- names(train_nrm)
frml <- as.formula(paste("medv ~", paste(nms[!nms %in% "medv"], collapse = " + ")))    eso es lo que ponen en el scrip original. La variable medv del paquete Boston es semejante a la de result of tratament con la diferencia que la mia es 0 y 1 , positivo o negativo. Me sigue saliendo esa advertencia

Comment: Asiel, sin poder ver los datos, no vamos a poder darte una respuesta. Si no puedes compartirlos, al menos agrega la estructura de los mismos `str(uno)`

Comment: 'data.frame': 90 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ sex                : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ age                : num  35 29 50 32 67 41 36 59 20 34 ...
 $ Time               : num  12 7 8 11.75 9.25 ...
 $ Number_of_Warts    : num  5 5 1 7 1 2 2 3 12 3 ...
 $ Type               : num  1 1 3 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 ...
 $ Area               : num  100 96 132 750 42 20 8 20 6 150 ...
 $ Result_of_Treatment: num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...

Comment: Asiel, sigue funcionando igual (bien),¿puedes mostrarnos que datos tienen `nms`?

Comment: Y por cierto, por como estás planteando la formula es lo mismo que hagas `as.formula("Result_of_Treatment ~ .")`

Comment: A ok reduzco la formula. El nms tiene la siguiente estructura> str(nms)
 chr [1:7] "sex" "age" "Time" "Number_of_Warts" "Type" "Area" ...

Comment: El error no te lo dá: `paste(nms[!nms %in% "Result_of_Treatment"], collapse = " + ")))`? que pasa si simplificas la formula tal como te lo indiqué?

Comment: Ya reduje el codigo y aun sigue dando la misma advertencia....cosa que con los datos boston no hace

Comment: Entonces el error debería estar en una sentencia que no has indicado en tu pregunta me parece... Si es así, por favor agregala.

Comment: Repliqué todo simulando datos y sale bien: Sexo <- sample(x = c(1,2), size = 1000, replace = TRUE); Edad <- floor(rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 45, sd = 13)) ;     Tiempo <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 12, sd = 3);
Tipo <- sample(x = c(1,2,3), size = 1000, replace = TRUE);
Area <- runif(n = 1000, min = 8, max = 750);
Tratamiento <- sample(x = c(0,1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE);
datos <- data.frame(Sexo, Edad, Tiempo, Tipo, Area, Tratamiento)